# Best way to implement "user to user" VoIP on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, p2p, voip

I have seen some great libraries to implement VoIP on iOS but they all apply for making calls to actual numbers. All I need is communication between users of my app. Siphon seems like a great option but you have to configure it with a service which allows you to make calls. All I need is communication between my users, maybe there is a better way to do this.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem because I'm exactly in the same situation right now, just user of my app make direct call to other app user via their ip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but,

all of what you describe is built in to **Game Kit** which is part of iOS.

You can use "Game Kit" for any sort of networking. (It does not have to be a game.) And person-to-person voice chat is completely built in. It's two or three lines of code.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I will check to see if it can do what i Need, I dont think Apple will let me use it because my app is not a game, all I need is users to be able to talk to each other.THANKS!

Comment: Thanks, I was actually implementing and that is why I forgot! It was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: but will game center chat work using internet connection using cellular network other than wifi???